# Is it possible to limit magit's log view to just commits from the current branch?

Tags: magit

Currently when I bring up the local magit log ("l l") it takes a fair amount of time. It would be nice for the log just to limit itself to the nearest merge base (e.g. vs origin/master) but I haven't been able to work out how to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`magit-log` accepts an optional `range` argument.  You can also do `l r l` followed by `origin/master` and then `HEAD`.

In Magit 2.x you can use `l o` to the same effect. In this case you would specify a range using [standard git range specifiers](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) (typically the 'double-dot' notation):
`l o` `origin/master..HEAD`

Comment: OK magit has changed the magit-log-popup because the "r" now takes me to the reflog....

Comment: what version of `magit` are you using?  It works for me with `magit-20141025.429`.

Comment: In Magit 2.x use `l o`

Comment: @rekado: yeah I'm using magit/next (which I think has just gone to MELPA). If you update for both key sequences I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer with the information from @phils comment.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with `v2.1.0` you can show logs for arbitrary branches, commits, and ranges using <kbd>l o  RET</kbd>.

It's also possible to log commits from multiple branches at once by separating them with comas: <kbd>l o , RET</kbd>.

Comment: As the question asks how to limit commits to what's happened since "the nearest merge base", I think you mean `l o origin/master..HEAD RET`, is that right? To avoid having to type so many characters every time ("origin/master..HEAD" is 20 characters!), is there a way to set this as the default/everywhere, e.g. always limit commits at `origin/master...HEAD` (or `(git merge-base master HEAD)~10`, say), i.e. never try to show *all* of the extensive history shared with `origin/master`?

Comment: BTW, magit is awesome, thank you so much for working on it and being here to answer questions. It has already enormously changed the way I work; I feel so much more powerful and productive. :-)